# Finding equation for energy density of matter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, astrophysics, universe, density

I'm trying to get an equation for the energy density of matter of the universe $\rho(t)$, assuming the number of particles is conserved and rest mass energy is much greater than kinetic energy. $\rho(t)$ should be a function of the scale factor of the universe $a(t)$, mass of particles $m$, and the number density of the particles $n(t_0)$.

I'm not sure how to approach this since $\rho(t)$ is in units of $\frac{Mass}{Length^3}$, $m$ is in units of $\frac{Mass}{Particle}$, $n(t_0)$ is in units of $\frac{Particle}{Length^3}$, and $a(t)$ is in units of $Length$. I guess there could be a factor of $\frac{a(t)}{a(t_0)}$ or $\frac{a(t_0)}{a(t)}$, but I don't know where I'd get that from.

Any help?

Comment: The [scale factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)) $a(t)$ is dimensionless.  And just to be sure, note that mass/length$^3$ is a *mass*-density not an *energy*-density.

Comment: Cross-posted on Astronomy SE

Answer (score 0):

One way you can think about this is to rephrase the questions as 'How would the energy density of a species dilute with expansion?'

Cold pressureless matter should dilute as $\rho\propto a^{-3}$. The energy density is entirely "contained" in the particles, so I expect energy density $\propto$ number density (e.g. if I double the length of the side of a box, the density will decrease by a factor of $1/8$ in a 3+1 dimensional universe). Once I have $\rho\propto a^{-3}$, plug this into the Friedmann equation $H^2=\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho$ and solve for $a(t)$.

By a similar line of reasoning, radiation should dilute as $\rho_{rad}\propto a^{-4}$. One contributing factor to $\rho_{rad}$ is $\propto a^{-3}$ which comes from the fact that the number of particles of radiation become more diluted when universe increases in size, and another contributing factor to $\rho_{rad}$ is $\propto a^{-1}$ because the energy of each particle decreases as the wavelength increases ($E\propto a^{-1}$).